# Spring can't read the @query annotation in spring Data Mongodb

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

Dears,

Iam getting **java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException** while trying to use the annotation org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query, and my web application is failed to start on the production server, **however the same code with the same WebSphere 9.0.0.8 and JDK1.8 on the testing servers are working fine with the details**, please advise what may cause such issue.

the full exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'registrationServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'newRegistrationRepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'newRegistrationRepo': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#e371922b' of type [org.springframework.data.repository.query.ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider] while setting bean property 'evaluationContextProvider'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#e371922b': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:592)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
```

here is the annotation in my java class

```
@Query("{'$and':[ {'cif':?0}, {'identification': ?1} , {'mobileNumber' : ?2}, {'applicationStatus' : 'Active' } ] }")
```

here is the maven dependency for the spring data mongo

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

here is the spring maven dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
     <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version> 
     <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        </exclusion>
     </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check once by putting `value` attribute in the query.

```
@Query(value="{'$and':[ {'cif':?0}, {'identification': ?1} , {'mobileNumber' : ?2}, {'applicationStatus' : 'Active' } ] }")
```

Comment: when i removed the annotation the application started successfully but for sure not behaving as expected, and the bad thing it's working on the testing servers :(

Comment: i've tried that but still getting the same exception, any other idea please?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `@Query` from `org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query`, you have to add following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

By the way its difficult to figure out why its working on the testing server

Comment: i tried that but still not working, however iam not using spring boot.

Comment: any other idea please?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, @Query is from
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query;

You can try easy query first to check the config problem.
like:

```
@Query("{ 'name' :  ?0 }")
@Query(value = "{ 'name' :  ?0 }", fields = "{ '_id': 0, 'name':1, 'age':1 }")
```

With complex query, you can meet the convention problem and Mapping / Parsing data problem also, please check step by step

Once more thing: By default, Mongo repository query by AND so your query can be reduce to:

```
'cif':?0, 'identification': ?1, 'mobileNumber' : ?2, 'applicationStatus' : 'Active'
```